# How do I add a new vertex group?

Tags: vertex-groups

I'm working on eye animations, but the right eye bone isn't in a vertex group.

How do I create a new Vertex Group that will appear in the Vertex Group section of the outliner? The section in the screenshot below.

[image: Vertex Groups in Outliner]

Answer (score 2):

Vertex groups can be added in Properties in Mesh Data tab:

[image]